# How to handle Long and different formats in a Play! Scala form?

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.0

In my model all associated accounts are `Long` not normal integers. However, when handling the Scala form in the new Play! 2.0 I can only validate an `Int` number in a form and not a `Long`.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaForms

Take the following form:

```
val clientForm: Form[Client] = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> number,
      "name" -> text(minLength = 4),
      "email" -> optional(text),
      "phone" -> optional(text),
      "address" -> text(minLength = 4),
      "city" -> text(minLength = 2),
      "province" -> text(minLength = 2),
      "account_id" -> number
    )
    (Client.apply)(Client.unapply)
  )
```

Where you see `account_id` I want to apply a `Long`, so how could I cast that in the simplest way possible? The `Client.apply` syntax is awesome for its simplicity but I'm open to options like mapping. Thanks!

Comment: You mean like `number.toLong`?

Comment: Exactly, except it's not even necessary to apply a conversion. check out my answer it's super simple!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a really awesome way to do this that looks like is missing from the documentation I linked in the question.

First, pull in Play! formats:
`import play.api.data.format.Formats._`

Then when defining the Form mapping use `of[]` syntax

and then the new form val will look like:

```
val clientForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> of[Long],
      "name" -> text(minLength = 4),
      "address" -> text(minLength = 4),
      "city" -> text(minLength = 2),
      "province" -> text(minLength = 2),
      "phone" -> optional(text),
      "email" -> optional(text),
      "account_id" -> of[Long]
    )(Client.apply)(Client.unapply)
  )
```

### Update: Using optional()

After further experimentation, I discovered that you can mix `of[]` with the Play! `optional` to meet the optional variables defined in your class.

So assume that the `account_id` above is optional...

```
"account_id" -> optional(of[Long])
```

Answer (score 7):

The previous answer definitely works, but it would be better to just use what is in `import play.api.data.Forms._` since you already have to import that for `optional` and `text`.

So instead you can use `longNumber`.

```
val clientForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "id" -> longNumber,
    "name" -> text(minLength = 4),
    "address" -> text(minLength = 4),
    "city" -> text(minLength = 2),
    "province" -> text(minLength = 2),
    "phone" -> optional(text),
    "email" -> optional(text),
    "account_id" -> optional(longNumber)
  )(Client.apply)(Client.unapply)
)
```